# How to make dynamically created content sharable

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a site that generates feed back based on user input using PHP and I would like to give people the option to share their feedback but I am not sure how.

I could sort of use Open Graph and populate the meta with PHP but it wont look very good and people may want to just share the site and not their feed back.

So ideally I would like to be able to share some type of HTML or a dynamically generated image.

Facebook's

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

didn't seem to have any good suggestion on this.

I would prefer to use PHP or some type of Javascript to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why won’t dynamically populated OG tags “look good”? If you want people to be able to share their own content, then individual URLs that hold individual OG meta information are a good way to do it. Plus, they can still share your “main” site in stead, if the want – by using its URL, that does not contain individual parameters. Your other options are using the Feed dialog (that allows to specify title, description, thumbnail of a link at runtime), or posting via API.

Comment: @CBroe I would be willing to settle of OG but another problem is FB constantly caches your OG data and you have to request a re-scrape in order to up date it do you know how to get around this? And by using the answer below I'm not having much luck getting FB to use the data from another URL it only seems to want to use the OG data from the current page, can you explain your method more?

Comment: Why, what would you have to constantly update? Does the user feedback by a specific user on a particular item change over time? If not, then that combination of user and item has a constant URL (including the parameters that refer to this particular combination), and then that needs to be scraped only once.

Comment: @CBroe Yes the user feedback is constantly changing by the unique user putting in different information, each session a user will get a couple different feed backs, they might want to share any or all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the best way to do this is to use [php imagecreate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) when you enter the `src=` for the image you simply put the GET values in the URL of the image that you are calling

```
 <img src="www.domain.com/myimage.png?textoverimage=customersname" />
```

But you would create the url with php so people can submit the value they want in the image via a simple html form, like this.

```
 <form method="get">
     <imput type="text" name="customername" />
     <imput type="submit"  />   
 </form>  

 <img src='www.domain.com/myimage.png?textoverimage=<?php echo $_GET["customername"];?>' />
```

Then the php imagecreate() will take those values and use them to put text over the image, and from that point it is easy to make the image shareable.

Now you are probably use to calling an image file in the `src` of a `<img />`but in this case you will actually call a php file and imagecreate() will generate the desired image out of that php file. below is what that php file will look like.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("http://domain.com/imagefile.jpg");

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
//imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw

$text = $_GET["textoverimage"];


$font = '/stocky.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 120, 170, $grey, $font, $text);


// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is the best way I have found to dynamically generate images with text over them.

Answer (score 1):

I think  It should be done in following way(Rather I have not tried it).
As facebook gives two things two include in your webpage first is javascript code and second one is html markup 
The sample html markup is following one

```
<div data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

You have to change data-href attribute with variable like `$url` and it should contain dynamically generated url 
If you want to share the current url You will use `$_SERVER` superglobal to constructing it.

Comment: I have tried this but I cannot get it to work it seems that no matter what Facebook only shows the OG meta content of the current page the button is on so I'm not sure what the URL even does because it doesn't seem to change anything. Another problem is FB constantly caches your OG data and you have to request a re scrape in order to up date it. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think php imagecreate() will actually end up being the best meth of doing this I'll keep everyone up dated on how it goins